# Is it possible for /etc/skel/.dotfile to have contents changed to match the username?

Tags: openbsd, useradd

I want to create a `~/.nanorc` file with a default `backupdir` path for each user:

```
set backup
set backupdir /var/nanobackup/username
```

Does this have to be customized after I create a new user or does `/etc/skel` or `useradd` have some syntax that will replace with the actual `username`?

Comment: Even with `nano` writing the backup files with the same permissions as the original (although its easy to forget that global reading is on by default), can't this pose some privacy issues? Instead of centralizing things, why not create a backup folder at each user's `/home`, setting `backupdir` to something like `~/nanobackup`?

Comment: I hadn't considered that, but my reasoning for putting it in `/var` is for when updating system files, though after some testing I just realized `doas` will save the backup in the `backupdir` configured for `root`. Hm.

Comment: Might take some tweaking to monitor some additional files, but a lot of stuff is automatically backed up at `/var/backups`. See `man changelist`.

Comment: It seems like that is part of daily security checks. I want to easily roll stuff back plus have record of previous revisions, but just a simple backup don't need full revision control system.

Comment: Not sure if `nano` expands it, but you could use the `$USER` env var. Take a look at `etckeeper` too which basically turns your whole `/etc` into a `git` repo.